# Python data structures, dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I hope somebody can help. I am using Python and I would like to be able to do the following.

I have a set of objects (shapes for example) and a series of commands to act on these objects. The commands have the a format of a command string followed by a variable number of parameters which can be strings or integers

For example the shape 'Rectangle' may have the following commands
'ChangeColor' 'green'
'FillStyle' 'hatch'
'Dimensions' 10 15
etc.....

What would be the best data structure to store this information. I need to be able to easily retrieve these commands from the data structure given the 'shape' of the object. Would a dictionary be the correct choice, I have never used these before

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off creating your own class:

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = "rectangle"
        self.color = "green"
        self.fillstyle = "hatch"
        # etc

    def ChangeColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

    # etc
```

Comment: Those are properties, but he wants to represent commands.  I don't think this is as useful.

Comment: @danben: just add a method inside the object definition: def ChangeColor(self, color): self.color = color.lower()

@recursive: there is a typo, you should replace 'this' with 'self'

Comment: Thanks dallo.  I added a method to illustrate how commands would work and fixed the "this" typo.  Damn C# in my brain.

Comment: @dalloliogm: that requires that an object knows about all the possible commands that could be executed on it though.  This problem strikes me more as an interpreted language type of thing.

Answer (score 2):

`dicts` are for when the order isn't important but you want store values for different names.

`lists` are ordered sequences of objects, usually of the same type and the position doesn't mean anything particular.

`tuples` are ordered sequences of objects, possibly of different types and each different position has a specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an object class and storing all of the values/commands within that object so that you can pass it around easily. (Similar to what [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44743/recursive) said).

However; you could also use a dictionary with the key being the object name and the values being a list containing possible commands.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a command could be represented as a list `[]` or tuple `()`, and so could a series of commands.  So one possibility is that you have a list of lists of strings.  Generally you want to use a dictionary only when you want to look up a value by key.  For example, if you knew the name of a command (wrt a shape) and wanted to know which parameters were passed to that command, you could have a dictionary mapping from string to list.

If you post more about how you plan to use this data, I could give a better answer.

Here is a link to the Python documentation on basic data structures, which should be very helpful:  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

**Edit**: in response to first comment, do you need to store the commands or just read them from input one by one and execute them?

Comment: Hi danben.

Thanks. I forgot to mention that the commands are executed in sequential order. So given a shape I would retrieve the first comammnd and execute. Once finished I would process the second command and so on

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

## Example

```
s = {'Rectangle':
        {'ChangeColor':'green','FillStyle':'hatch',
         'Dimension1': 10, 'Dimension2':15}}
s['Triangle'] = {'ChangeColor':'red','FillStyle':'hatch',
         'Dimension1': 10, 'Dimension2':15, 'Dimension3':5}

for k, v in s.iteritems():
    print k
    for k1, v1 in v.iteritems():
        print "   ", k1, "=", v1
```

Result:

```
Triangle
    Dimension1 = 10
    Dimension2 = 15
    Dimension3 = 5
    ChangeColor = red
    FillStyle = hatch
Rectangle
    Dimension1 = 10
    Dimension2 = 15
    ChangeColor = green
    FillStyle = hatch
```

Comment: Yes thanks,  how would i handle command with no parameter, i.e a key with no value. Thanks

Comment: After print k, write:
if not v:
   print "  empty"
   continue

Answer (score 0):

I would store the commands as a list of lists, or of tuples, depending on whether or not I thought I'd modify commands.  Note that argument unpacking in Python makes for a very simple mechanism for executing these commands, e.g.:

```
class Shape(object):
    def background(self, color):
        print "background:", color
    def foreground(self, color):
        print "foreground:", color
    def rect(self, left, top, right, bottom):
        print "rect:", left, top, right, bottom
    def execute_commands(self, command_list):
        for command in command_list:
            if hasattr(self, command[0]):
                getattr(self, command[0])(*command[1:])

>>> s = Shape()
>>> c = [('background', 'blue'), ('foreground', 'yellow'), ('rect', 10, 0, 20, 20)]
>>> s.execute_commands(c)
background: blue
foreground: yellow
rect: 10 0 20 20
```